Why CURRENT_DATE in SSIS works but not in SQL?
I have a fully functional legacy SSIS system which I  have inherited.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 to view the packages.  I also have a connection to Microsoft SQL using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.
Note.  I am trying to be extremely accurate here and It's entirely possible that I am misrepresenting this somehow.  All I know is the version of the software I use to access these systems, I do not know if those are the same versions they are run in (if that makes sense)?
In Visual Studio.  I see steps such as an "Execute SQL Task Editor" (this is what the popup window shows when I go to edit it) and in this step I see a query which contains the function name 'CURRENT_DATE'.  Everything appears to be working correctly, however, If I take that same exact SQL command out of the SSIS package and run it directly on the database it does not work saying that CURRENT_DATE is not a command.
Why?
I think i need to be more clear here.  The question is not why does the command not work.  I already know that.  The question is why DOES it work in SSIS?  I need to know what commands are working in SSIS and why because we are going to migrate to a cloud based version of it (or something) and I am trying to determine what will break.
screenshots



Correct, CURRENT_DATE, and it works.  the question is why?

Can you pop a screenshot of the Execute SQL Task showing the query. And then look at the Connection listed on the Execute SQL Task and open that Connection Manager up and see what database that is pointing at. If it's a SQL Server... You can make your own functions but that'd still require parenthesis. Oh and what is the provider (OLE/ADO/ODBC) ODBC has some "weird" conventions, maybe we're got one of those going on here

yes, one sec...

SSIS doesn't change how SQL Server parses and executes SQL commands. Are you sure you aren't connecting to a different database? Perhaps someone created a CURRENT_DATE() function that returns GETDATE() ?

SQL Server connection strings don't use uid. SQL Server doesn't have TO_CHAR. What is RUDW ?

i've got several meetings, i'll get back to this in a few hours.  thanks all.

That's not SQL Server. That's all there is to it. It may be MySQL or Oracle

SQL Server doesn't have current_date. Since a big part of what SSIS is for is moving data between different databases, it's likely the package you're looking is also connecting to something like a postgress, oracle, or mysql db for transfer to or from the SQL Server.

Okay, now that we can see the connection, it's using an ODBC datasource. You'll need to look in the data source to see what driver it's using.

Oh, and why is the EndDate in this package come before the start date? That seems very strange. And why 1186 days? The number arbitrary, as it's not a multiple of any number of months, weeks, or years. And why take 16 days if we're on a Sunday, but only day the rest of the week? There's a lot in that package that doesn't make sense.

Okay, doing some checking, and I strongly suspect this is talking to Snowflake.

Still in meetings...  yes, this is also talking to snowflake, curios how you know that.  as for the 1186 days, i put that in. it's normally 1 day but my current task is to grab data from Jan 1 2021 which was 1186 days ago (as of yesterday)

@DallasCaley We can find that because, while SQL is standardized, NONE of the database platforms 100% follow the standard, and date/datetime functions are one of the major places where we find variation. Snowflake seems to be the ONLY database that supports all of the various date features used in the sample code.

As others have deduced, while the SSIS package may run on the SQL Server, it works because the package also connects to a different location and database. It's using an ODBC connection to talk to a different kind of database entirely, with different functions for handling dates... a common situation among SQL dialects.
Doing some digging for a platform supporting ALL of DAYNAME, TO_CHAR() (both with and without a format argument), and CURRENT_DATE, and I strongly suspect this is talking to a Snowflake database.
If it helps, the direct SQL Server translation of that code looks like this:
SELECT
    FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyy/MM/dd/') FileDate,
    CASE WHEN datepart(DW, getdate()) = 0 
         THEN format(dateadd(day, -16, getdate()),'yyyy-MM-dd') 
         ELSE format(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()),'yyyy-MM-dd') END StartDate,
    FORMAT(dateadd(day, -1186, getdate()), 'MM/dd/yyyy') EndDate

But it raises a number of items that cumulatively lead me to question the quality of the original package in the first place (any 1-3 of these would be fine, but ALL of them together raises my eyebrows):

Why the trailing / on file date?
Why does the end date come before the start date?
Why 1186 days, which has no significance relative to weeks, months, or years?
Why go back 16 days (half a month) based on a weekday like Sunday, instead of a day of the month?
Why repeat the entire TO_CHAR() expression inside the CASE, instead of just using the expression to produce the integer date offset?
Why are we producing strings at all, instead of actual date objects, so the client code or report tool can format to fit the environment?


This is the correct answer, I was aware that Snowflake was part of the process the entire time, but i thought it was only on the sending end of the ETL transaction.  It appears that sometimes we are both reading from and writing to Snowflake databases.

To answer the other questions,  i'm responsible for the 1186 number, this is the number of days back to Jan 1st 2021 which is what the client wanted.  For all of the other questions you'd have to dig up the person who wrote this and god knows how long they have been dead, gone or whatnot.

CURRENT_DATE is not a SQL Server function. You either need to use GETDATE() or GETUTCDATE() for the UTC version. See How do I get CURRENT_DATE in MSSQL? for another explanation.

I understand that.  Everything I've googled points to that.  What I don't understand is why it actually works?  This is important to me because we are planning a server migration and I've got hundreds of commands with potentially bad stuff in them and I want to know what things are bad without having to go through each one.

Your SSIS package is running on SQL Server 2014.
The Execute SQL Task you show is using an ODBC provider to use a DSN to point to your RUDW database.
TO_CHAR is available in at least PostgreSQL and Oracle
CURRENT_DATE is specified in the SQL 92 spec
SQLLite appears to support CURRENT_DATE but that hardly seems an appropriate RDBMS choice for something called a data warehouse.
PostgreSQL has a CURRENT_DATE function and seems much more inline with the snippet of SQL code you've shown but as panagiotis kanavos points out, DAYNAME is not a PG function
Oracle does have CURRENT_DATE and DAYNAME
MySQL does have CURRENT_DATE and DAYNAME as well. Interestingly enough, it supports both CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE() syntax - how fun!
I would think a Oracle query would have to query against DUAL, or similar to be valid so seems like MySQL is likely your RUDW
Remote desktop into the server where this package runs and see what your ODBC connection show.

64 bit C:\WINDOWS\system32\odbcad32.exe
32 bit C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

No, those are not typos, that's how things "work" with windows.

Why not Oracle or MySQL? Both TO_CHAR and CURRENT_DATE() are available in Oracle and MySQL. The DAYNAME function doesn't exist in PostgreSQL.
